# Bash here document with expect not working

Tags: bash, expect

I have some code written in an expect file:

```
  #!./expect -f

  set timeout -1
  spawn /path/to/command --foo param1 --bar param2 --password
  expect "Password for baz which is prompted on the console.: "
  send "pass\r"
  expect "> "
  send "print\r"
  expect "> "
  send -- "\r"
```

When I run it the output is:

```
spawn /path/to/command --foo param1  --bar param2 --password
Password for baz which is prompted on the console.: 
> print

{"stuff"}

> 
>
```

I have some code in a here doc in bash:

```
variable=$(/usr/bin/expect <<HEREKALpxT5KZu
  set timeout -1
  spawn /path/to/command --foo param1 --bar param2 --password
  expect "Password for baz which is prompted on the console.: "
  send "pass\r"
  expect "> "
  send "print\r"
  expect "> "
  send -- "\r"
HEREKALpxT5KZu
)
```

I expect this code to produce the exact same output as running the expect file, but the output when I print the variable is:

```
spawn /path/to/command --foo param1 --bar param2 --password
Password for baz which is prompted on the console.: 
>
```

There is no second ">" and no {"stuff"}. It's like the print command is never sent. Also, when I add "interact" at the end, it only works for the expect file, not the here doc.

Comment: use `expect -d` to enable debugging.

Comment: Perhaps your actual expect script body needs to be protected from shell parameter expansion: try `variable=$(expect <<'HEREKALpxT5KZu'` to "single quote" the entire heredoc